# How can I evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big[ \cot(\pi\sqrt{100n^2+n+1}\Big]$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry, summation

While scrolling through questions in **Brilliant** I saw the following question on limit[image]

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big[ \cot(\pi\sqrt{100n^2+n+1}\Big]$$

If we take $n^2$ outside square root we are left with ${100+\frac {1} {n} +\frac {1}{n^2}}$ inside square root and we can't use expansion of $\sqrt{(1+\frac{1}{n})}$ because of three terms inside square root.

If we use
$$\pi\cot(\pi x)=\frac{1}{x}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{1}{x-k}+\frac{1}{x+k}\Big)$$

with $x=\sqrt{100n^2+n+1}$,then our limit becomes

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\Big[\frac{1}{ \sqrt{100n^2+n+1} }+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{100n^2+n+1} -k}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{100n^2+n+1} +k}\Big)\Big]$$

Now I got stuck on summation with this method.

How can we show that this limit equals those messy square roots?

Comment: Why can't you expand?  You have $\sqrt{1+(\frac1{100}n^{-1}+\frac1{100}n^{-2})}=1+\frac1{200}n^{-1}+\dots$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\sqrt{100n^2+n+1}=10n\sqrt{1+\dfrac{n+1}{100n^2}}\sim10n+\dfrac{n+1}{20n}\to10n+\frac1{20}.$$

So the question amounts to finding the cotangent of $\dfrac\pi{20}=9°$.

The following table can be very useful: [https://math.la.asu.edu/~surgent/mat170/Exact_Trig_Values.pdf](https://math.la.asu.edu/%7Esurgent/mat170/Exact_Trig_Values.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, take n out common from the squareroot

> $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\cot \left(\pi \sqrt{100n^2+n+1}\right)=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\cot \left(\frac{\pi \sqrt{100+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}}{\frac{1}{n}}\right)$

now let $t=\frac{1}{n}$, and we have

> $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\cot \left(\frac{\pi \sqrt{100+t+t^2}}{t}\right)$

As it is a 0/0 form, we can now use the L's hospital rule:

> $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\cot \left(\frac{\pi \sqrt{100+t+t^2}}{t}\right)=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\cot \left(\frac{\frac{\pi \left(1+2t\right)}{2\sqrt{100+t+t^2}}}{1}\right)=\cot \left(\frac{\pi }{20}\right)$

Can you proceed from here?